# how to call inner class method or variable from outer jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

this is my index.jsp page:

```
<html>

<body>
<%!
public class myclass{
  private final int foo = 42;

  public int getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

how to call myclass method or variable in other jsp page ?
please help me .

Comment: This should be on StackOverflow. It's not an admin question.

Answer (score 4):

You don't from any "other" JSP. Those declarations should be treated as local to the JSP. If you need a class to be used by multiple JSPs, write it as a separate Java source file, compile it, and include it in your webapp in WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use something like

<%@ include file="/myFile.jsp" % >

???